# Transfer or download file from website directly to your site server

Tags: php, ftp, transfer

I want to download the wordpress from its website ([wordpress.org](http://www.wordpress.org/)) to my ftp host directly.
I heard that there is a way to do it directly instead of download it and then upload again.

How can I do it? using ftp or php.

**edit:**
I do not have ssh access to the server. it is a free server at: [FreeWebHostingArea.com](http://FreeWebHostingArea.com/)

**edit2:**
Some websites offered a way to send fie to the target server by php. but I need a way to download (not send) file to my ftp server.

Comment: I have editted it to be more clear.

Comment: You probably want to change 'ftp' in the title to 'php' and remove the ftp tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little search I found how to download it. Here is the code:

```
<?php


$new_file = file_get_contents('http://wordpress.org/latest.zip') or exit('unable to open from wordpress');

$current = fopen('latest.zip','c') or exit("Unable to open file!");
fclose($current);

chmod('latest.zip',0777);


file_put_contents('latest.zip',$new_file);

echo 'Done';

?>
```

This script first opens the "latest.zip" from [wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/)
Then opens a fie named "latest.zip" in the host. and close it. It should set the `chmod` in order to write to file.
At last it puts the contents of downloaded file to "latest.zip" to the host.

Important: The folder which you upload this "script.php" should have write access in order to create the "latest.zip" file.